# Python CGI: How to split large output into pages?

Tags: python, cgi

How do i split the python-cgi output into pages. 
sample loop structure:

While 1:

```
if x is true:
   c.execute("select m from n where id=%s")
   gene=c.fetchall()
   print "%s", (gene),
else:
   print "NA"

if y is true:
   c.execute("select p from q where id=%s")
   protein=c.fetchall()
   print "%s", (protein),
else:
   print "NA"

print "\n"
```

the output is millions of lines. I want to breakdown the output into pages..like 50 lines per page. How do i do that? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A rough sketch how to proceed:

1. You have to code a parameter `page` into your url, which indicates: "show the page number `page`". This is something like `http://xxx.abc.de/genes?page=3`, and you have to modify your script to retrieve this parameter. This can be done with http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#
2. You have to modify your selects, such that elements `page ... page+pagesize-1` are retrieved. MySQL has the `limit` modifier for this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html
3. You have to generate links on your page which link to the previous page and to the following (if they exist). According to the example above this would be `http://xxx.abc.de/genes?page=2` and `http://xxx.abc.de/genes?page=4`

Answer (score 0):

Use "LIMIT offset,limit" sql statement. Also you can buffer your output, and write data breaking it by pages(files)

Comment: I guess, i cannot modify the select command, as i have multiple select commands in the loop which will be printed out in a row. DO you have a link to an example code?

Comment: do you need 50 lines from each sql request or from all data response? If you have multiple sql you can set limit like this: Limit offset,round(50/number_of_sql_queries)